# Java PircBot Connection timeout

Tags: java, bots, irc

My ChatBot can't connect to twitch.tv IRC Servers and i dont know why.
The Main Class is the same as for other Bots and they have no problem connecting.
The only thing that is different is that the bot got some command outputs with ASCII Codes
and when i saved the project in eclipse, i got a warning about i need to chance Encoding so i saved the Project as UTF-8

Could that cause the connection issues?

greetings

Code of MyBotMain below:

```
public class MyBotMain {


        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            // Now start our bot up.
            MyBot bot = new MyBot();

            // Enable debugging output.
            bot.setVerbose(true);
            bot.setEncoding("UTF-8");

            // Connect to the IRC server.
            bot.connect("irc.twitch.tv", 6667, "oauth:htxqplqpigeordiz1bk7vmtw155hpet");
            bot.joinChannel("#yeroise");
        }

}
```

error i got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jibble.pircbot.PircBot.connect(PircBot.java:140)
    at partyBot.MyBotMain.main(MyBotMain.java:16)
```

here is my MyBot Class:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.jibble.pircbot.*;


public class MyBot extends PircBot {

    public static int rngnumber;
    public static int rngkeks;
    public static int rngparty;
    public static Random randomint;
    public static String kekscontainer;


    public String drinksuser;
    public boolean party;

    Timer partytimer;

    public MyBot() {
        this.setName("ParteyBot");
        this.setMessageDelay(1800);
        randomint = new Random();
        kekscontainer = null;
        drinksuser = null;
        party = false;
    }

    public void onMessage(final String channel, String sender,
                       String login, String hostname, String message) {


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Glückskeks
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!glückskeks")) {
            if(kekscontainer == null){
                kekscontainer = sender;
                keksgenerator(channel);
            }
        }


        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!party") && party == false) {
            sendMessage(channel,"( •_•) ( •_•)>⌐■-■ (⌐■_■) PARTY TIME YEAAA");

            partytimer = new Timer();

            partytimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    partygenerator(channel);
                }
            }, 7*1000);   
        }

            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!stopparty")) {
                sendMessage(channel,"(⌐■_■)  ( •_•)>⌐■-■  ( •_•) Okay Leute, zusammen packen.. Party ist vorbei =(");
                partytimer.cancel();
                partytimer.purge();
            }        


            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!cmd")) {
                sendMessage(channel,"Befehle: !party, !stopparty, !dance, !drink username");
            }

        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!party") && party == true) {
            sendMessage(channel,"(⌐■_■) PARTY HAAAAAARD!");
        }


        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!yero")) {
            sendMessage(channel,"Meister Yero ist einfach too Stronk!");
        }


        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!dance")){
            sendMessage(channel," (>*,*)> (>*,*)> (>*,*)>  DANCE PARTY <(*,*<) <(*,*<) <(*,*<)");
            sendMessage(channel," (>*,*)> <(*,*<) (>*,*)>  PARTY HARD ALL DAY <(*,*<) (>*,*)> <(*,*<)");
        }


        if (message.toLowerCase().startsWith("!drink ")) { 

            try{

            drinksuser = message.toLowerCase().split("!drink ")[1];

            }catch(Exception e) {

            }

            for(int i = 0; i < this.getUsers("#yeroise").length; i++){
                System.out.println("i="+i);
                System.out.println("getusername="+this.getUsers("#yeroise")[i].getNick());
                if (drinksuser.equals(this.getUsers("#yeroise")[i].getNick())){
                    sendMessage(channel, "Überreicht "+drinksuser+" einen Drink. Stösschen!");
                }

            }
        }


    }



    public static int randomNumber(int range){
        MyBot.rngnumber = MyBot.randomint.nextInt(range);
        return MyBot.rngnumber;
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //keksi-Modul-Generator
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void partygenerator(String channel){
        MyBot.rngparty = randomNumber(11);
        switch(MyBot.rngparty){
            case 0: sendMessage(channel, "Loos Party-Peoples!! Hände in die Luft!! macht RADAU!!! nz nz nz");
            break;
            case 1: sendMessage(channel, "*Licht aus* Weiß hier jemand wo der Sicherungskasten ist? Ok nvm! PARTEYYY");
            break;
            case 2: sendMessage(channel, "ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)╯ TAAAANZEEEEEN   ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)╯");
            break;
            case 3: sendMessage(channel, "♪┏(°.°)┛┗(°.°)┓ Fühlt die Melody! ┗(°.°)┛┏(°.°)┓ ♪");
            break;
            case 4: sendMessage(channel, "٩(̾●̮̮̃̾•̃̾)۶٩(̾●̮̮̃̾•̃̾)۶٩(̾●̮̮̃̾•̃̾)۶٩(̾●̮̮̃̾•̃̾)۶٩(̾●̮̮̃̾•̃̾)۶٩(̾●̮̮̃̾•̃̾)۶");
            break;
            case 5: sendMessage(channel, "(>*_*)> (>*_*)> (>*_*)> na na na na na na na");
            break;
            case 6: sendMessage(channel, "ʕʘ̅͜ʘ̅ʔ na na na na na na na ʕʘ̅͜ʘ̅ʔ");
            break;
            case 7: sendMessage(channel, "(⦿⽘⦿) EEEEEPIIIC *AUSRAST* (⦿⽘⦿)");
            break;
            case 8: sendMessage(channel, "(ツ) (ツ) (ツ) Derp Derp Derp (ツ) (ツ) (ツ)");
            break;
            case 9: sendMessage(channel, "¸¸♬·¯·♩¸¸♪·¯·♫¸¸ Soo Schöön =(  ¸¸♬·¯·♩¸¸♪·¯·♫¸¸");
            break;
            case 10: sendMessage(channel, "┏(-_-)┛┗(-_- )┓Ihr seid die besten! ┗(-_-)┛┏(-_-)┓");
            break;
    }
        MyBot.kekscontainer = null;
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //keksi-Modul-Generator
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void keksgenerator(String channel){
        MyBot.rngkeks = randomNumber(101);
        switch(MyBot.rngkeks){
            case 0: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Ein Weg wird erst dann ein Weg wenn einer ihn geht.");
            break;
            case 1: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Bier hinterläßt keine Rotweinflecken!");
            break;
            case 2: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Die Wohnung bleibt beim Bohren von Dübellöchern staubfrei, wenn Sie die Wand vorher in den Garten tragen!");
            break;
            case 3: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wenn du eine Entscheidung treffen musst und du triffst sie nicht, ist dies auc heine Entscheidung!");
            break;
            case 4: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Je mehr Käse desto mehr Löcher, je mehr Löcher, desto weniger Käse! Fazit: Je mehr Käse, desto weniger Käse!");
            break;
            case 5: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Das Geheimnis jeder Macht besteht darin, zu wissen, dass andere noch feiger sind als wir.");
            break;
            case 6: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Eine in die Wand geschlagene Schraube hält besser wie ein reingedrehter Nagel!");
            break;
            case 7: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Spinat schmeckt wesentlich besser, wenn man ihn kurz vor dem servieren durch ein Schnitzel ersetzt!");
            break;
            case 8: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Nur wer selbst brennt, kann Feuer in anderen entfachen!");
            break;
            case 9: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wer zuletzt lacht.. hat es als letzter verstanden!");
            break;
            case 10: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Ein halbleeres Glas Wein ist zwar zugleich ein halbvolles, aber eine halbe Lüge mitnichten eine halbe Wahrheit.");
            break;
            case 11: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Diese Nachricht zerstört sich in wenigen Sekunden selbst!");
            break;
            case 12: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wer für alles offen ist, kann nicht ganz dicht sein.");
            break;
            case 13: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Diskussion ist die Kunst, wohlüberlegt aneinander vorbeizureden.");
            break;
            case 14: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Phantasie ist wichtiger als Wissen, denn Wissen ist begrenzt.");
            break;
            case 15: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Das Geheimnis einer glücklichen Ehe liegt in vier Worten: Du hast recht Liebling!");
            break;
            case 16: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Sich alleine zu freuen, ist trauriger, als zu zweit zu leiden.");
            break;
            case 17: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wenn zwei Menschen immer dasselbe denken, ist einer von ihnen überflüssig!");
            break;
            case 18: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wer den Kopf in den Sand steckt wird am Hinterteil erkannt!");
            break;
            case 19: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Erfolg steigt nur zu Kopf, wenn dort der erforderliche Hohlraum vorhanden ist.");
            break;
            case 20: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Es ist auf jeden Fall besser heimlich schlau zu sein, als unheimlich blöd!");
            break;
            case 22: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Fahre nie schneller, als dein Schutzengel fliegen kann!");
            break;
            case 23: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Faulheit ist die Kunst, sich auszuruhen, bevor man müde wird");
            break;
            case 24: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Die meisten Probleme lösen sich von alleine. Man darf sie nur nicht dabei stören!");
            break;
            case 25: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wenn dir das Leben eine Zitrone reicht, mach Limonade daraus!");
            break;
            case 26: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Lache nie über die Dummheit der anderen. Sie ist deine Chance!");
            break;
            case 27: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Alles hat grenzen, nur die Dummheit ist unendlich");
            break;
            case 28: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Sei lieber ein Optimist und ein Trottel, als ein Pessimist der Recht hat.");
            break;
            case 29: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Im nachhinein weiss man es immer besser.");
            break;
            case 30: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Hilfe, ich bin in einer Glückskeksfabrik gefangen!");
            break;
            case 31: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Einige Menschen träumen von dem grossen Glück, andere von Keksen.");
            break;
            case 32: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wer der Sonne entgegenwandert, läßt den Schatten hinter sich.");
            break;
            case 33: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Verurteile niemanden, bevor du nicht in seiner Lage warst.");
            break;
            case 34: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wer den größten Pinsel besitzt, ist noch lange nicht der beste Maler.");
            break;
            case 35: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Bist du sicher dass du eben Hühnchen gegessen hast?");
            break;
            case 36: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wer in der Jugend Bäume pflanzt, kann sich im Alter in deren Schatten setzen.");
            break;
            case 37: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Hilfe, ich werde in einer Glückskeksfabrik als Geisel festgehalten.");
            break;
            case 38: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Auch die besessensten Vegetarier beißen nicht gern ins Gras");
            break;
            case 39: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Es gibt so viele kleine Quellen des Glücks, an denen die Menschen auf der Suche nach dem großen Strom vorübergehen.");
            break;
            case 40: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Das Gras wächst nicht schneller, wenn man daran zieht!");
            break;
            case 41: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...   Die kürzeste Verbindung zwischen zwei Punkten ist gewöhnlich wegen Bauarbeiten gesperrt.");
            break;
            case 42: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Der Anfang ist die Hälfte des Ganzen.");
            break;
            case 43: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Früh arbeiten macht nur früh müde!");
            break;
            case 44: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Eine Überzeugung zu haben, ist einen gute Sache, doch seine Ansicht auch zu verwirklichen - dazu gehört Kraft.");
            break;
            case 45: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Iss keinen gelben Schnee!");
            break;
            case 46: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Je länger der Tee zieht, desto kälter wird er.");
            break;
            case 47: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Je weniger Haare man hat, desto mehr Gesicht muss man waschen");
            break;
            case 48: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Konsequenz heißt, auch einen Holzweg zu Ende gehen");
            break;
            case 49: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Lieber am Busen der Natur, als am Arsch der Welt.");
            break;
            case 50: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Nicht nachlassen, sonst misslingt etwas.");
            break;
            case 51: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Spontanität muss sorgfältig geplant werden!");
            break;
            case 52: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Schlimmer als ein Elefant im Porzellanladen, ist ein Igel in der Kondomfabrik.");
            break;
            case 53: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wer mit Dreck wirft, verliert an Boden.");
            break;
            case 54: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wer Ordnung hält, ist nur zu faul zum Suchen.");
            break;
            case 55: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Auch ein Affe fällt mal vom Baum.");
            break;
            case 56: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Es gibt nichts Schlechtes, an dem nicht auch etwas Gutes ist.");
            break;
            case 57: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Das Leben ist wie ein Teller Suppe. Nur wenn du heiß bist, wird geblasen");
            break;
            case 58: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Die Kreditkartennummer von Homer Simpsons ist 5784 3653 4341 0709");
            break;
            case 59: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Glück ist nichts, bis du es in Händen hälst.");
            break;
            case 60: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Entschlossenheit hat keine Rückkehr.");
            break;
            case 61: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Ein alter Freund ist besser als zwei neue.");
            break;
            case 62: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Die Dinge verstecken sich oft vor dem, der sie sucht. Lässt man sie gewähren, so zeigen sie sich.");
            break;
            case 63: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Nur weil du in den Zug gekotzt hast, bist du noch nicht bahnbrechend.");
            break;
            case 64: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Vitamine sind gesund. Kalorien schmecken besser!");
            break;
            case 65: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wenn man seinen Kopf gegen eine Wand schlägt, verbraucht man 150 Kalorien pro Stunde. ");
            break;
            case 66: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Nicht jeder Ratschlag hat Hand und Fuß.");
            break;
            case 67: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wer es eilig hat, stolpert.");
            break;
            case 68: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Besser weniger, aber besser.");
            break;
            case 69: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Die gute Zeit fällt nicht vom Himmel, sondern Wir schaffen sie selbst.");
            break;
            case 70: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Es gehört mehr Mut dazu, seine Meinung zu ändern, als ihr treu zu bleiben.");
            break;
            case 71: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Es ist besser, ein Licht zu entzünden, als auf die Dunkelheit zu schimpfen.");
            break;
            case 72: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Nur wer das Schöne in sich trägt, kann sie in der Welt finden.");
            break;
            case 73: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Es ist schwer verschüttetes Wasser wieder zu sammeln.");
            break;
            case 74: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Hoffnung ist wie der Zucker im Tee: Auch wenn sie klein ist, versüßt sie alles.");
            break;
            case 75: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Nutze den Tag!");
            break;
            case 76: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Das Ende ist die Krönung einer Sache.");
            break;
            case 77: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Eine lange Reise beginnt mit dem ersten Schritt.");
            break;
            case 78: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Ein törichter Freund ist eine größere Plage als ein weiser Feind.");
            break;
            case 79: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Je weiter Du Dich entfernt glaubst, desto näher bist Du!");
            break;
            case 80: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wer sich über des andern Glück freut, dem blüht sein eigenes.");
            break;
            case 81: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wer nicht kann, wie er will, muß wollen, wie er kann.");
            break;
            case 82: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Es ist nicht wenig Zeit , was Wir haben, sondern es ist viel, was Wir nicht nützten.");
            break;
            case 83: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Zeit existiert nur, um zu verhindern, daß alles sofort geschieht.");
            break;
            case 84: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Mache weiter oder höre auf aber warte nicht.");
            break;
            case 85: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Sie erwägen Aktionen, die sich für Sie auszahlen werden.");
            break;
            case 86: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Über Vergangenes mache dir keine Sorge, dem Kommenden wende dich zu.");
            break;
            case 87: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Aus den Augen, aus dem Sinn.");
            break;
            case 88: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Wer barfuß geht, den drücken die Schuhe nicht.");
            break;
            case 89: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Heute beginnt der erste Tag vom Rest Deines Lebens.");
            break;
            case 90: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Unternehme Leichtes, als wäre es schwer und Schweres als wäre es leicht.");
            break;
            case 91: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Bohre den Brunnen, ehe du Durst hast.");
            break;
            case 92: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Alle Dinge kannst du nicht tun.");
            break;
            case 93: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Der, der den Weg eines anderen geht, ist nicht weise.");
            break;
            case 94: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Erfolg hat nur, wer etwas tut, während er auf den Erfolg wartet.");
            break;
            case 95: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Immer nach der Sternen greifen, aber die Füße auf dem Boden behalten.");
            break;
            case 96: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Nur wer an die Zukunft glaubt, glaubt an die Gegenwart.");
            break;
            case 97: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Das Schicksal meint es gut mit Dir.");
            break;
            case 98: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Ebbe folgt nicht auf Ebbe. Dazwischen ist die Flut.");
            break;
            case 99: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Ich weiss wo du wohnst! ;)");
            break;
            case 100: sendMessage(channel, MyBot.kekscontainer+" Öffnet einen Glückskeks...  Ein rollender Stein setzt kein Moos an.");
            break;
    }
        MyBot.kekscontainer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error message when running your code?

Comment: Yes, i did edit it above.

Comment: Where did you set the Bots Username? As claimed here http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/1302780-twitch-irc the bots Username has to be an Twitch Username

Comment: The Twitch username is set in the MyBot.Java Class. Of Course its a username of a twitch acount i created for the bot purposes. should i edit the post above and write down the MyBot aswell?

Comment: Yeah.. As I cannot see a problem in your code posted so far..

Comment: Have you tried to test it with minimal functionality? Only setting the required login information and comment everything else out and try to connect?

Comment: Hey, i tried that now and it isnt working. i tried an alternate host with only an IP and no oauth token and it worked to connect. why im not able to connect to the twitch irc? My Other bots doing the same auth method and codings lik ethis one and the others work^^ its strange :c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59272/discussion-between-user3220962-and-iralution).